# SwiftUI - difference between accent, foreground and tint color?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

Could someone please explain to me the difference between **Foreground**, **Tint** and **Accent** color?

Linguistically:

- **Tint** means shade
- **Accent** means bright colors
- **Foreground** means regular colors

Programmatically:

- *What is **Tint**?*
- **Foreground** is that primary color that changes the text/view color
- **Accent color** is the secondary color

Also, why does **Accent** not work in the code below?

```
Text("Accent Color")
.accentColor(.blue)
```

[image: Text stays black]

Comment: `Color.accentColor` is the global color for buttons and other controls, not including Text. However you can change your example to `.foregroundStyle(Color.accentColor)` to work.

Comment: "tint" is something from UIKIt - in SwiftUI it's known as "accent" instead. You can use `.accentColor` to set the "accentColor" - but once again, this only works for controls.

Comment: "foregroundColor" is different depending on the View. So for `Text`, it will change the text color. Then for `Circle`, it will change the fill color.

Comment: Foreground color is for text, accent color is for buttons, tint color is used in UIKit

Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 17):

In iOS 15 Beta there is a new method to set tint.

Documentation says:

**Accent Color**

> Use accentColor(_:) when you want to apply a broad theme color to your app’s user interface. Some styles of controls use the accent color as a default tint color.

**Tint**

> Use this method to override the default accent color for this view. Unlike an app’s accent color, which can be overridden by user preference, the tint color is always respected and should be used as a way to provide additional meaning to the control.

**Foreground Color**

> The foreground color to use when displaying this view. Pass nil to remove any custom foreground color and to allow the system or the container to provide its own foreground color. If a container-specific override doesn’t exist, the system uses the primary color.

Foreground color usually applies to text based views (Text, Labels, etc.) Images (as a template).

Accent/Tint colors apply to controls (including images in controls, e.g. buttons, pickers etc).

Accent Color sets the global overall color for the app, tint is for one-off overrides on controls.

Another way to put it is Foreground Color is for everything non-interactive, Accent/Tint are for interactive items.

Comment: Hey Chad. It seems that the accentColor(_:) is being deprecated. But I don't see the alternative to set the global accent colour perhaps since the TabBar? Thanks

Comment: @JakubGawecki Not deprecated according to docs https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/color/accentcolor

Comment: @Bretsko yes deprecated according to XCode. The docs only show deprecation if it is currently deprecated

Answer (score 1):

In terms of your code example, the new way to achieve what that was trying to specify is:

```
Text("Accent Color")
    .foregroundColor(.blue)
```

Or, if you want to apply the current system accent colour, you can use:

```
Text("Accent Color")
    .foregroundStyle(Color.accentColor)
```

or:

```
Text("Accent Color")
    .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
```

Accent color is a special color that not only changes based on the system's current accent color, but also displays as grey when the underlying item is set to .disabled.

Whether the use of `.accentColor` will be desirable will of course depend on the context of how you are intending to use it.